# Changing system of coordinates given a pair of vector fields.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-fields

Given a pair of fields $X,Y$ in $\mathbb R^2$, how can one deduce that exists a system of coordinates $(u,v)$ defined in a open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ such that 
$$X = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \text{ and }Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial v}? \quad (I)$$

I'm not familiar with this kind of argument. Take of example the following fields:

1. $X = y \frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.
2. $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

I don't know if the Lie brackets make any difference to conclude, but in the first case $[X,Y] = -x \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and in the second one the corresponding Lie Bracket is zero. How can I see if there exists such a system satisfying $(I)$?

Comment: You're in $\Bbb R^2$, right? So no $z$'s or $\partial/\partial z$'s !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Suppose we have coordinates $(u, v)$ in which the coordinate representations of $X, Y$ are $X = \partial_u$ and $Y = \partial_v$; what is $[X, Y]$?

Comment: it must be zero. So we only can find such coordinates in the second case... but how can I find this new coordinates?

Comment: In fact, this condition actually characterizes when we can find such coordinates: If $X, Y$ are linearly independent and $[X, Y] = 0$ in some neighborhood of a point $p$, there are coordinates $(u, v)$ near that point such that $X = \partial_u, Y = \partial_v$. In particular, we do not need to find an explicit formula for the coordinates to know that they exist.

Comment: If you do want to find coordinates, let $\chi$ and $\upsilon$ denote the flows of $X, Y$ and define the parameterization $\phi(u, v) := (\upsilon_v \circ \chi_u)(p)$. The identities $X = \partial_u$ and $Y = \partial_v$ follow from the definition of flow and the fact that $\chi_u, \upsilon_v$ commute. All of this works the same for manifolds of higher dimension $n$, too, though there we need $n$ pairwise commuting vector fields instead of just $2$ of them.